# Cannot load QML plugin if folder is put into nested folder

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml, qt6

maybe someone have an idea how fix such problem:
By following that tutorial https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/interfaceframework/qtinterfaceframework-interfaceframework-qface-tutorial-example.html and using examples I managed to create working simulation backend.

So if my project structure looks like that:

```
-root
--CMakeLists.txt
--app
  --CMakeLists.txt
  --src
  --res
--backend_simulator
  --CMakeLists.txt
--frontentd
  --CMakeLists.txt
--imports
  --CMakeLists.txt
```

main.cpp:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                 &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
        QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
// adding my imports folder
engine.addImportPath(app.applicationDirPath() + "/imports");

engine.load(url);
```

Everything works well, but only if I moved `imports`, `backend_simulator` and `frontend` into new `middleware` folder which simply added those folders by CMakeLists, plugin cannot be loaded.

```
-root
--CMakeLists.txt
--app
  --CMakeLists.txt
  --src
  --res
--middleware
  --CMakeLists.txt
  --backend_simulator
    --CMakeLists.txt
  --frontentd
    --CMakeLists.txt
  --imports
    --CMakeLists.txt
```

My import path is also changed to:

```
engine.addImportPath(app.applicationDirPath() + "/middleware/imports");
```

During runtime I got:

> path/to/build/my_module.dll: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: You probably have something wrong with your cmake make sure that `middleware` folder is being copied to the build folder.

Comment: Middleware folder is copied correctly and everything looks exactly the same. That's strange to me. Maybe qml cannot find some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to putting all output folders in the build directory and get rid of Middleware folder.
In such case QML have no problem with locating plugins and qmls.